# Request is missing required HTTP header

Tags: python-2.7, api, postman, scrapy

I have requested an api by postman but it didn't response required page, however it says: **Request is missing required HTTP header ''**

When I went to website developer section/Network tab in XHR, it shows required output.

```
Request Headers: Accept:application/json, text/plain, / Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8 Connection:keep-alive Host:panthera.api.yuppcdn.net Origin:test.com Referer:test.com User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36 Query String Parameters view source view URL encoded
```

How can I resolve this?
Please help.

Comment: In the network tab, look at the header of the request and see what are you missing in the header request on postman.

Comment: I have looked at the header of the request but how can we know what is missing in header request

Comment: Can you post the header of the XHR request here?

Comment: General:
Request URL:http://test.com
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:183.87.86.153:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Response Headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:86400
Cache-Control:max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:3582
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 25 Aug 2017 05:04:58 GMT
Expires:Fri, 25 Aug 2017 05:04:58 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:spray-can/1.3.3
Vary:Accept-Encoding

Comment: Request Headers:
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:panthera.api.yuppcdn.net
Origin:http://test.com
Referer:http://test.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded

Comment: Query String Parameters:
tenant_id:3
session_key:
user_id:
device_type:5
box_id:
ip:58.84.61.10
location:IN
version:1.0
section:popula
lang:ENG
count:24
offset:0

Comment: Do you set header parameter `Accept:application/json` in post man? I think the API does not respond to requests without this parameter.

Comment: yes, I have set this header parameter in postman but still got the same response:
Request is missing required HTTP header ''

Comment: @NMoeini: do you have any idea how to proceed now ?

Comment: I haven't mentioned the original API here

Comment: Well, there is not enough information then. The API code or a public working API should be provided for help. Set the request headers as much as you can. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Request an API contract from the developer who's API you are invoking. This API contract must contain what headers are required for the successful invocation of the API.
If it a public API it should also contain its contracts published or documented on the respective site from where you are referring the API specs.